# Посчитать количество каждой цифры и создать объект

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, counter

У меня есть функция, которая извлекает числа из аргументов и возвращает его в виде строки:

```js
function countNumber(smth) {
    return String(smth.match(/\d+/));
}

console.log(countNumber('123098h76gfdd')); //=>12309876
```

```js
countNumbers('erer384jj4444666888jfd123');
// => {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 5, '6': 3, '8': 4}
countNumbers('jdjjka000466588kkkfs662555');
// => {'0': 3, '2': 1, '4': 1, '5': 4, '6': 4, '8': 2}
countNumbers(''); // => {}
```

Теперь мне нужно посчитать количество каждой цифры и создать объект. например, в конце это должно выглядеть так, как показано выше:

Как это сделать правильно? Есть идеи? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: `[..."3844444666888"].reduce((acc, digit) => ({ ...acc, [digit]: (acc[digit] || 0) + 1 }), {})`

Comment: тут обычно общаются на русском языке

Comment: Кстати да, Анастасия, задавайте Ваши вопросы на русском языке на данном сайте. Это есть в правилах.

Comment: Из очереди проверок: Поменяйте текст вопроса на русский язык

Comment: Кстати, твоя функция работает неверно: `countNumber('123098h76gfdd') == "123098"`, должно быть как у тебя в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const countDigits = str => (str.match(/\d/g) || []).reduce(
  (rslt, digit) => ((rslt[digit] = ~~rslt[digit] + 1), rslt)
, {}); 

const printObj = obj => console.log(
  JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[,:]/g, '$& ')
); 

printObj(countDigits('erer384jj4444666888jfd123'));
// => {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 5, '6': 3, '8': 4}
printObj(countDigits('jdjjka000466588kkkfs662555'));
// => {'0': 3, '2': 1, '4': 1, '5': 4, '6': 4, '8': 2}
printObj(countDigits('')); // => {}
```

Вместо `(str.match(/\d/g) || [])` можно `[...str.replace(/\D/g, '')]` - результат будет одинаков, но у второго варианта возможен +1 проход по символам строки (зависит от внутренней реализации строк, и спред-оператора).

Answer (score 0):

Или так.

```
var allowed = /\d+/;
var results = Array.prototype.reduce.call("123099998h76gfdd", function (data, letter) {
    if (allowed.test(letter)) {
        letter = letter.toLowerCase();
        if (data[letter] === undefined) {
            data[letter] = 0;
        }
        data[letter] += 1;
    }
    return data;
}, {});

var o = new Object();
for (var letter in results) {
    o[letter] = results[letter]
}
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто создать еще один объект, перевести строку в массив, и пробежаться по массиву:

```js
var res = new Object();
"ssd243fs20324fs".split("").filter(char => char >= '0' && char <= '9')
  .forEach(d => res[d] = (res[d] || 0) + 1)
```

Сначала выпоняется фильтрация символов: проверка, что символ -- цифра. Далее для каждой цифры инкриментируется счётчик в `res`.

Результат: `{ 0: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2 }`

Как я писал выше в комментарии, функция (автора вопроса) получения цифр не верная (нет цифр 76):

```
String('123098h76gfdd'.match(/\d+/)) == "123098"
```

PS: в старых браузерах или IE может не заработать. Но это поправить легко, и это касается и других ответов.

PPS: на мой взгяд, всякие `reduce`, используемые в других ответах, мало понятны новичку. Зато каждый, изучающий язык, знает про циклы, т.е. понять `forEach` должно быть не сложно.